# Editing Gradient Mask Once Applied

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image that I am trying to fade on the right side in Photoshop CC. I created a layer mask on the image and applied the gradient. Looks okay but I want to fine tune the gradient look. I cannot find a way to edit the gradient that was applied. The only way I can figure is to delete the gradient, adjust the gradient then keep reapplying. There has to be a way to edit it once it is applied so I can have a live preview while editing. Any ideas? I tried Alt+click but that still does not work.

Comment: Can you include an image of what you've done, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a layer mask, you can clip the layer to a gradient fill layer. This will allow you to adjust the gradient as you like.

1. Create a Gradient Fill Layer
2. Move the layer you want to fade to just above the gradient fill
   layer in the layers panel
3. Right-click on the main image layer (not the name, but the blank
   space to the right of the name) and select "Create Clipping Mask"
4. Double-click the gradient icon on the gradient fill layer to open
   the gradient properties.
5. Adjust the angle of the gradient as desired.
6. Click on the gradient that is displayed in the dropdown (don't open
   the dropdown, just click on the gradient that is displayed next to
   "Gradient:" to open the Gradient Editor.
7. Adjust the gradient as you like.
   [image]

[image]

[image]